# How to prevent form submit when input is focused and enable it when out of focused with vuejs2?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on a form with a vue component that has an autocomplete functionality, I would like to let user select from suggestions. I am handling keyup events for up, down and enter. Unfortunately, when enter is hit, the form is submitted. I would like to prevent form submit if the input field is focused. I have tried using v-on:submit.prevent in the form tag but that disables form submit completely and I need to create an separate form submit function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this. But I don't really know vue so I might be wrong.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  new Vue({
    data() {
      return {
        focused: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit: function() {
        return this.focused;
      }
    }
  }).$mount('#app')
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <form v-on:submit="onSubmit">
      <input type="text" @focus="focused = true" @blur="focused = false" />
      <button :disabled="focused">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```